не загружается картинка на sfml
что тут не так?
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
using namespace sf;
int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow win(sf::VideoMode(1280, 720), L"ПОДВИГИИИИИИ ЕХУУУУ!!!!!!");
    Image icon;
    if (!icon.loadFromFile("img\planet.png"))
    {
        // Обработка ошибки, если текстура не загружена
        return 8;
    }
    win.setIcon(32, 32, icon.getPixelsPtr());
    
    while (win.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (win.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                win.close();
        }

        win.clear();
        win.display();
    }
    return 0;
}


Не указан абсолютный путь.

Чем собирается проект?

Вместо передачи объекта icon в метод loadFromFile, вы должны передавать путь к изображению в виде строки.
Замените это herotexture.loadFromFile(icon); на herotexture.loadFromFile("img/planet.png");
Если и так нет - убедитесь, что путь к изображению "img/planet.png" указывает на правильное местоположение файла относительно рабочего каталога программы.
Или можете обработать ошибку
if (!herotexture.loadFromFile("img/planet.png"))
    {
        // Обработка ошибки, если текстура не загружена
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }


ну я про проверку хотел узнать почему нету и как бы я так и назвал папку в проекте img и фотка планеты planet.png но почему нету C:\C++\sfml\img\planet.png

мне пишет в консоли    Failed to load image "img/plan.png". Reason: Unable to open file
Trying to access the pixels of an empty image   и как это сделать?
